# Bacon.js stream with some okay errors

Tags: functional-programming, bacon.js

The result of a `PUT` operation against a database, is sometimes ok even if it doesn't come back as a HTTP code `200`.

In this specific case I want to treat `400` as another okay error, but struggle to come up with an elegant way of doing it.

```
# stream from a promise any non 200 is fail
putter = Bacon.fromPromise @_exec 'PUT', '/some/resource', {}   
errors = putter.errors().mapError(errBody)    # now errors are normal values
badErrors = errors.filter(statusIsnt(400)).flatMap (body) -> 
  return new Bacon.Error body                 # and now they are errors again
okErrors = errors.filter(statusIs(400)).flatMap (body) -> {}
noError = putter.mapError().filter (v) -> v?  # attempt to get rid of errors
Bacon.mergeAll noError, okErrors, badErrors   # combine to get result stream
```

I come from a promises background, and I find the above somewhat clumsy, which leads me to conclude I'm missing something. Compare:

```
@_exec 'PUT', '/some/resource', {}
.fail (err) ->
  if err.body.status == 400 # ok
    return {}
  else
    throw err
```

Comment: I think the "best" answer will depend on what you wish to do with the result value. You could also look at EventStream.subscribe, which receives all events, including errors.

Further, I don't think your comparison is fair, since if all you wanted to do was throw non-400 errors, that would be a simple use of onError.

Comment: Fair point. This is init code. I want to do stuff depending on whether it succeeds or fails. The promise I could at this point just chain on a `.then` to go on after init, same with `.onValue` from the `mergeAll`. Both 200 answers (which ends up in `noError`) and these "okay" errors should give me a point to continue after init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withHandler` with `Bacon.Error` for `throw` and (implicit) `Bacon.Next` for `result`. But the code will look very similar to your handling already in promise. Actually promise version has less boilerplate.

Compare your promise version

```
promise = @_exec('PUT', '/some/resource', {})
recovered = promise.fail (err) ->
  # 400 is ok. make it ok already in promise
  if err?.body?.status == 400 then {} else throw err.body
result = Bacon.fromPromise recovered
```

and `withHandler` Bacon "only" version

```
promise = @_exec('PUT', '/some/resource', {})
stream = Bacon.fromPromise promise
result = stream.withHandler (event) ->
  if (event.hasValue())
    @push(event)
  else
    # error
    if event.error?.body?.status == 400 then
      @push({})
    else
      @push(event)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution for this specific scenario is to amend the result already in the promise, but I can easily envisage cases where you can't do that.

```
Bacon.fromPromise @_exec('PUT', '/some/resource', {}).fail (err) ->
    # 400 is ok. make it ok already in promise
    if err?.body?.status == 400 then {} else throw err.body
```

Surely there must be a better functional approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`withHandler` is an underlying method that lets you operate on Events of all types. Within it you can call @push, which will send errors to the error stream and values to the value streeam. Perhaps the following:

```
Bacon.fromPromise(@_exec('PUT', '/some/resource', {}))
    .withHandler((event) ->
        if event.isError && event.error.body?.status? == 400
            @push(new Bacon.Next({}))
        else
            @push(event)
    )
```

Comment: This looks almost exactly what I want, but it doesn't work as expected. The returned Bacon.Error goes into the *value* stream. 
`Bacon.once(new Bacon.Error('fail')).mapError((e) -> new Bacon.Error(e)).subscribe (e) -> console.log e`
# as expected: <error> fail, <end>

`Bacon.once(new Bacon.Error('fail')).mapError((e) -> new Bacon.Error(e)).onError (e) -> console.log e`
# unexpected: /nothing/

`Bacon.once(new Bacon.Error('fail')).mapError((e) -> new Bacon.Error(e)).onValue (e) -> console.log e`
# unexpected: <error> fail

Comment: Oh, I understand. It looks like Oleg is right -- you want withHandler, although I think there could be a simpler implementation. I'll amend my answer.